# Javascript Library which could read the systems properties namely os, system architecture dynamically?

Tags: javascript, linux, windows

I am in a process to build an application(Javascript) which runs on a browser and dynamically retrieve the details of the clients machine such as operating system and its version, system architecture(32/64 bit), and which could connect to the terminal and run few commands. I wanted it to work both on ubuntu and windows machines.

Comment: The OS version and 32/64 is typcally in the browser user agent string - that information is generally correct, but can be messed with by the user if desired.  Terminal commands will not be permitted by browser Javascript for security reasons so these could only be done by code with higher privileges (like a browser add-on) and would likely have to use some platform-specific code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please let me which technology would support building these sort of applications?